# How to get push key in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the Key generated when I push data to Firebase database. I want to handle them with my own function,

So the issue is when the user fills the form he sends the data to our real-time DB, contained in this data are some images (**optional**), and I don't need to let the image object empty in DB, so how to handle this, and when the user needs to send an image I want to save this image in the same Order, not in New Order.

Node

[image: Node]

Here is my function

```
handleOrder = () => {
    const { nameOfProblem, description, userId, imageOfPrblem, providerId } = this.state;
    const PushData = firebase.database().ref("request/" + providerId + "/" + userId + "/orders/");
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref("users/" + userId + "/UserImageOrders/" + path);
    let file = imageOfPrblem.uri;
    const path = "img_" + imageOfPrblem.fileName;
    var newOrderRef = PushData.push({
        nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
        description: description,
    });
    if (file) {
        let keyG = newOrderRef.key; // Key Generated with .push()
        PushData.child(keyG).update({ // didn't updated the key generated just add new element with new key !!
            imageOfPrblem: imageOfPrblem
        });
        ref.put(file).then(() => {
            console.log("File uploaded..")
        });
    }
}

handleImages = () => {
    const options = {
        title: "Select Images!",
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: "images"
        }
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
        console.log("Response = ", response);
        if (response.uri) {
            this.setState({ imageOfPrblem: response });
        }
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log("User cancelled image picker");
        } else if (response.error) {
            console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
            alert(response.customButton);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine for me:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/55912103");

var newChildRef = ref.push({ firstChild: true });
console.log("new key: "+newChildRef.key);
ref.child(newChildRef.key).update({ secondChild: true });
```

After running this code, I end up with this JSON in the new child whose key gets logged:

```
"-LdgLWu_wBNNicFlPDGj" : {
  "firstChild" : true,
  "secondChild" : true
}
```

Live demo: https://jsbin.com/hovoleh/edit?js,console

Live JSON: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/55912103.json?print=pretty

---

Update: if you just want to write both the existing data and new data to a *new* location:

```
var newOrderRef = PushData.push({
    nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
    description: description,
});
if (file) {
    let keyG = newOrderRef.key; // Key Generated with .push()
    PushData.child(keyG).update({
        nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
        description: description,
        imageOfPrblem: imageOfPrblem
    });
    ref.put(file).then(() => {
        console.log("File uploaded..")
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it's not what I want, let's say I want to just push firstChild, then in the new query I want to update and add second child but here I want this updated to the previous key not create new Key,  check this capture, https://imgur.com/yyy7fxE

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what my code does: it first writes `firstChild: true` to a new location, and then updates that location adding `secondChild: true`.

Comment: No :/ just add a new location with first and second Child Not updates the last location :]

Answer (score 1):

The push ID from any Firebase snapshot `ref` is in `ref.name()`.

Comment: not work the image doesn't saved in the DB, can you check the functions I was manipulated them

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the author created a post but maybe someone will find it useful.

The above answers are a bit wrong because, for example, after: newChildRef

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/55912103");

var newChildRef = ref.push({ firstChild: true });
```

newChildRef  <--- promise

```
ref = rdb.ref('name_of_your_ref');
    var childRef = ref.push({
        IdUser: currentUserId,
        ProductCategory: pCategory,
        ProductDescription: pDesc,
        ProductId: pId,
        ProductName: pName,
        ProductPrice: pPrice,
        ProductQuantity: pQuan
    }).catch(err => console.log(err.message));
    childRef.then(item => {
        ref.child(item.key).update({
            IdKey: item.key
        }).then(() => history.push('/delivery/basket'));
    });
```

Greetings, Matthew